# jquery mobile XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

So the problem is that I'm not making any ajax calls. When I include jquery.mobile-1.1.0 all of my script files genereate this error. The weirder part is that everything works.
 So for instance I have

```
<script src="myScripts.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Afterwards I get the XMLHttpRequest errors... but all of these js files load...
Any ideas as to why this is happening? I can't have the app run on localhost by the way, I need it to run as a stand alone file.

Comment: I think may be you need to place the `myscripts.js` below the `jquery.js` and `jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js`..

Comment: yeah I need jquery for myscripts so cant put jquery below myscripts or I'll get jquery undefined error